# Аналог scanf в Java

Tags: java, input

Добрый день, есть ли аналог метода scanf из C++ на Java?
Он мне нужен для того, чтобы парсить строку чисел, сразу инициализируя созданные переменные, не создавая массив строк.

Например:

Входная строка

```
1 2 3 //разделено пробелами
```

Вместо того, чтобы писать

```
String[] line = reader.readLine().split(" ");

int n = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
int x = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
```

Реализовать что-то наподобие

```
int n, x, y;
scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &x, &y); //как в C++
```

Comment: [java.util.Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java нет аналога scanf. Самое близкое - это класс java.util.Scanner. Пользоваться им можно примерно так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int x = sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();
```